# HTML/CSS: Center Align Tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

Problem: the html/css below displays the tabs fine but I would like to align them to the center. I have tried various ways but they still align to the left. How can I align the three tabs to the center and keep them inline-block? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

I also attached a picture for reference. [image]

```css
main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: ;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs:checked+label {
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input class="tabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  <section id="content1">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 2</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 3</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>
  <section id="content3">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 3</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take at it using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I added some holders and some css code

```css
main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: ;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.tabs-grouper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-holder">
  <div class="tabs-grouper">
    <input class="tabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>

    <input class="tabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>

    <input class="tabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `text-align: center` to `main`, and then reset it all on `section` using `text-align:left`.

It will affect *`inline-block` elements*, but not your `section` being `block`, though as descendants might inherit it, the *reset* will take care of that.

Stack snippet

```css
main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;                   /*  added  */
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;                     /*  added  */
}

.tabs {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: ;
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: ;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs:checked+label {
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input class="tabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  <section id="content1">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 2</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 3</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>
  <section id="content3">
    <img src="/images/autocode.jpeg" alt="Doctor Icon" class="key-modules- 
        innter-image" height="180" width="auto">
    <h1 class="key-modules-inner-div-header">Tab 3</h1>
    <p class="key-modules-inner-div-paragraph">random text will go here
    </p>
    <a href="/align-providers">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="learn-button">Learn 
         more</button>
    </a>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the tabs in a div and then set the wrapper css to margin:auto and width:20% or whatever keeps them inline.

Answer (score -1):

I use the always good cheat, center tags!

```
<center>
  <input class="tabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>

  <input class="tabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
</center>
```

Comment: Hey @awtrimpe - thanks for the tip. Always is nice to learn something new. This works but it, unfortunately, centers everything. I only want the three inputs centered. I moved the tags to that section but broke the logic. The seconds (1-3) no longer open if I do that.

Comment: @AndrewK Do not use `<center>`, its been deprecated since years back.